# How to get render submenus using current route in react-router v4?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

My code looks similar to this :https://www.techiediaries.com/react-router-dom-v4/

```
  <div className="base">
    <header>
      <p>React Router v4 Browser Example</p>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li><Link to='/'>Home</Link></li>
            <li><Link to='/about'>About</Link></li>
            <li><Link to='/about/one'>AboutOne</Link></li>
            <li><Link to='/about/two'>AboutTwo</Link></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div className="container">
      <Route path="/" exact component={HomePage} />
      <Route path="/about" component={AboutPage} />
```

I want to be able to only show the links to AboutOne and AboutTwo if the user is on `about`, `about/one`, or `about/two` (i.e. a page and its subpages). Unfortunately with `<Link`s and `<NavLink`s you can't manually set the active class (as far as I can tell), else I'd just do a `visibility: visible` style for it. So I guess I have two problems that are preventing me from accomplishing this: first, I can't set when the `Link` is active, and second, I don't know how to get the current route to determine if the user is on a page or its subpages. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You could wrap the submenu links in a if statement then use a callback to check if you are on the about path. You can check your path in React Router 4 using this.props.location.pathname

not sure what react style coding you are using but it could go like this

```
ifOnAboutPath() {
  return this.props.location.pathname === 'about' ? true : false;
}

render() {
const showSubmenu = <ul><li><Link to='/about/one'>AboutOne</Link></li>
        <li><Link to='/about/two'>AboutTwo</Link></li></ul>;
const subMenu = this.ifOnAboutPath.bind(this) ? showSubmenu : '';

<div className="base">
<header>
  <p>React Router v4 Browser Example</p>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><Link to='/'>Home</Link></li>
        <li><Link to='/about'>About</Link></li>
        subMenu
      </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
<div className="container">
  <Route path="/" exact component={HomePage} />
  <Route path="/about" component={AboutPage} />
```

Comment: Do you have to do anything specific to get location to come in through the props? I have tried this, and it's `undefined`

Comment: import {withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
here is a great example of how to use https://hackernoon.com/withrouter-advanced-features-of-react-router-for-single-page-apps-42b2a1a0d315 as I'm unsure of your app component hirarechy

Answer (score 2):

It appears I was looking at some janky react router docs that hadn't been updated. You can just the `isActive` prop. So, for future googlers/bingers/duckduckgoers:

```
  <NavLink
    to="/v/user"
    isActive={(match, location) => {
      console.log(match, location);
      return location.pathname.startsWith("/v/user");
    }}
    className="nav-sub-link"
    activeClassName="activeThing"
  >
    Submenu!
  </NavLink>

  .nav-sub-link:not(.activeThing) {
    visibility: hidden;
  }

  .nav-sub-link {
    visibility: visible;
    //then some more styles
  }
```